# Simple multiple directories CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

I just would like to create my CMakeLists.txt like this, but the CMake guide is not that user friendly for beginners, I have already researched too much, do not downvote, please.

I have seen some solutions including in the  `add_executable()` every source file manually, but I would like to make it more generic. Also, I would not like to use the  `file(GLOB SOURCES *.cpp *.h)`.

By the way, I am just attempting to create a Unix Makefile with the command

```
cmake -G 'Unix Makefiles'..
```

How can I do this?

```
CMakeLists.txt
build/
    ...
project/
    CMakeLists.txt
    Inc/
        CMakeLists.txt
        *.h
    Src/
        CMakeLists.txt
        main.cpp
        *.cpp
```

I have so far for the main directory/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)

project(my_project)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++2a")

add_subdirectory(project)
```

for the project/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_subdirectory(Inc)
add_subdirectory(Src)

add_executable(exec ${Sources})

target_link_libraries(exec ${Headers})
```

For the Inc/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(
    Headers
    H1.h
    H2.h
    ...
    Hn.h
)
```

and for the Src/CMakeLists.txt

```
set(Sources main.cpp
        Src1.cpp
        Src2.cpp
        ...
        Srcn.cpp
    )
```

As it is so far, it throws the following error

```
-- Version: 7.0.3
-- Build type:
-- CXX_STANDARD: 11
-- Required features: cxx_variadic_templates
-- Configuring done
CMake Error: Cannot determine link language for target "exec".
CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: exec
CMake Error: Cannot determine link language for target "Headers".
CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: Headers
-- Generating done
CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
```

Comment: Doesn't `Src` and `Inc` belong to the same project? Why would you create so many CMakeLists? `but I would like to make it more generic. Also, I would not like to use the` So what would you want to use instead and how do you want to make it "generic"?

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to make a library out of only headers and no source files. I know the concept of header only libraries exist but they don't really compile into .lib files.

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes, they belong to the same project, I just want to separate files in different folders, also as a didactic way to learn for future projects. In regards to the number of CMakeLists, I just don't want to write that many lines on the upper CMakeLists. Generic, such that If somebody else want to add an additional file, it will be as simple as modifying the local CMakeList

Comment: @drescherjm As I mentioned, I am just beginner with CMake, I have attempted several versions, but I just do not want too many lines on the same CMakeLists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> add_library(
>    Headers
>    H1.h
>    H2.h
> ```

does *not* add a include directory to search path. It only adds the headers to sources - and because headers are not compiled, it effectively does nothing. You can do that with `target_include_directories`. Because cmake doesn't know if these are C or C++ headers, it cannot determine the link language.

> ```
> add_subdirectory(Src)
> add_executable(exec ${Sources})
> ```

`add_subdirectory` introduces a new "scope". Variables set in `add_subdirectory` are not visible outside, unless you set them with `PARENT_SCOPE` like `set(var "value" PARENT_SCOPE)`. `${Sources}` is effectively empty, so it does `add_executable(exec)` with no sources, so cmake cannot determine the link language.

> ```
> target_link_libraries(exec ${Headers})
> ```

A target is not a variable. `${Headers}` is empty. To link with a target just use it's name.

I also subjectively advice do not use mixed case variables (and folder names).

You could:

```
# project/CMakeLists.txt
include(Inc/CMakeLists.txt)
include(Src/CMakeLists.txt)
add_executable(exec ${exec_sources} ${exec_headers})
target_include_directories(exec PUBLIC Inc)

# Inc/CMakeLists.txt
set(exec_headers
    Inc/H1.h
    Inc/H2.h
    ...
    Inc/Hn.h
)

# Src/CMakeLists.txt    
set(exec_sources
        Src/main.cpp
        Src/Src1.cpp
        Src/Src2.cpp
        ...
        Src/Srcn.cpp
)
# Instead of `Src/` in front you could write a `foreach()` loop.
```

but I do not see a point in having so many CMakeLists.txt. Just have one file:

```
# project/CMakeLists.txt
include(Inc/CMakeLists.txt)
include(Src/CMakeLists.txt)
add_executable(exec
        Src/main.cpp
        Src/Src1.cpp
        Src/Src2.cpp
        ...
        Src/Srcn.cpp

    Inc/H1.h
    Inc/H2.h
    ...
    Inc/Hn.h
)
target_include_direcotories(exec PUBLIC Inc)
```

Och, there is also [`target_sources`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_sources.html) you could use, so you could also do it like this I think:

```
# project/CMakeLists.txt
add_executable(exec ${exec_sources} ${exec_headers})
add_subdirectory(Inc)
add_subdirectory(Src)

# Inc/CMakeLists.txt
target_include_directories(exec PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
target_sources(exec PRIVATE 
    H1.h
    H2.h
    ...
    Hn.h
)

# Src/CMakeLists.txt    
target_sources(exec PRIVATE
        main.cpp
        Src1.cpp
        Src2.cpp
        ...
        Srcn.cpp
)
```